# Calendar date validation isn't returning correct boolean

Tags: android, date, validation, calendar, java-calendar

I'm trying to validate a calendar date, but when it is validated, the code returns false regardless of input.

```
String strDateOfBirth = userInputArrayList.get(7) + "/" + userInputArrayList.get(8) + "/" + userInputArrayList.get(9);
Log.d(TAG, "1Date of Birth: " + strDateOfBirth);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
Date dtDateOfBirth = parseDate(strDateOfBirth, sdf);

//Convert to epoch millis
long dobmillis = dtDateOfBirth.getTime();
Log.d(TAG, "date of birth in milli: " + dobmillis);

//Current time in epoch millis
long currmillis = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
Log.d(TAG, "current date in milli: " + currmillis);

Log.d(TAG, "less than: " + (19L * 365L * 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L));
Log.d(TAG, "less than: " + (11L * 365L * 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L));

if ((currmillis - dobmillis) > (19L * 365L * 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L)) {
    //More than 19 years
    txtCalenderErrorCreateAccountPage.setText("must be 19 years of age");
    nextPage = false;
} else if ((currmillis - dobmillis) < (11L * 365L * 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L)) {
    //less than 11 years
    txtCalenderErrorCreateAccountPage.setText("must be 11 years of age");
    nextPage = false;
} else {             
    txtCalenderErrorCreateAccountPage.setText("correct");
}


public Date parseDate(String date, SimpleDateFormat sdf) {
    try {
        Date d = sdf.parse(date);
        return d;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        showToast("There has been an error");
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want the date to return true when the date of birth means the user will be between 11 and 19 years of age.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Assuming that you are programming for Andoird consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. I tried with `28/07/2008` and `28/08/2000` and both times got `Correct DOB`. Could you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) *with example input*, please?

Answer (score 0):

```
String strDateOfBirth = userInputArrayList.get(7) + "/" + userInputArrayList.get(8) + "/" + userInputArrayList.get(9);
Log.d(TAG, "1Date of Birth: " + strDateOfBirth);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
Date dtDateOfBirth = parseDate(strDateOfBirth, sdf);

//Convert to epoch millis
long dobmillis = dtDateOfBirth.getTime();
Log.d(TAG, "date of birth in milli: " + dobmillis);

//Current time in epoch millis
long currmillis = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
Log.d(TAG, "current date in milli: " + currmillis);

Log.d(TAG, "less than: " + (19L * 365L * 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L));
Log.d(TAG, "less than: " + (11L * 365L * 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L));

if ((currmillis - dobmillis) > (19L * 365L * 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L)) {
  //More than 19 years
  txtCalenderErrorCreateAccountPage.setText("more than 19 years of age");
} else if ((currmillis - dobmillis) < (11L * 365L * 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L)) {
  //less than 11 years
  txtCalenderErrorCreateAccountPage.setText("less than 11 years of age");
  nextPage = false;
} else {             
  txtCalenderErrorCreateAccountPage.setText("11 - 19");
  nextPage = false;
}


  public Date parseDate(String date, SimpleDateFormat sdf) {
    try {
      Date d = sdf.parse(date);
      return d;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      showToast("There has been an error");
      return null;
  }
}
```

Basically reduced the code complexity and removed any and all timezone dependencies by converting everything to epoch

Comment: Thank you! Would checking for the user being younger than 11 be the same but with 11 instead of 19 and a less than sign instead of greater than sign?

Comment: same code.... instead of 19 use 11 and the "else" part will give u less than or equal to 11

Comment: when I enter a date that gives an age less than 11 (specifically 1/12/2008), it treats it as if it's age is between 11 and 19, any suggestions?

Comment: post your code again buddy, idk what you have done now

Comment: here now my code will give u less than 11, 11 to 19 and more than 19

Comment: I entered the previous date and it's still returning the age as being between 11 and 19, when it isn't, even with the new code

Comment: well buddy it actually is more than 11 and less than 19 isnt it? 1/12/2008 -> will be 11 on 1/12/2019 so it is more than 11 years and less than 19

Comment: the current date is only 21/08/2019 (21st of August) and my input is 1/12/2019 (1st of December), so it should be less than 11

Comment: Post your parseDate function

Comment: just added parseDate

Comment: you had misplaced the correct condition in the wrong scope

Answer (score 0):

### The problem

You have used `mm` (*Minute in hour*) instead of `MM` (*Month in year*).

Using the correct symbol will fix the problem. However, the `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

### Solution using `java.time`, the modern API:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/u", Locale.ENGLISH);
        
        // Test
        Stream.of(
                28 + "/" + 5 + "/" + 2000,
                28 + "/" + 5 + "/" + 2008,
                28 + "/" + 5 + "/" + 2012
        ).forEach(strDateOfBirth -> {
            LocalDate dtDateOfBirth = LocalDate.parse(strDateOfBirth, dtf);
            LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
            long years = ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(dtDateOfBirth, today);
            System.out.println( 
                                years > 19 ? "must be 19 years of age" :
                                years < 11 ? "must be 11 years of age" :
                                             "correct"
            );
        });     
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
must be 19 years of age
correct
must be 11 years of age
```

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>